# Apply filter to the table function

Tags: r, filter

I'm looking for a way to execute a simple task faster than I am currently able to.

I want to use the `table` function in R on part of a dataframe. Of course it would be possible to first use `subset` and then `table`, but this is a bit tedious. (In my case, during a first inspection of the data, I want to check the frequency of NAs on individual variables in a multi-national survey for each of the 25 participating countries. So I'd need to create 25 subsets, make the table, and then remove the subsets again because I don't need them anymore.)

Here is some example data:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
b <- c(1,3,99,99,2,3,2,99,1,1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(a,b)
```

And this is the workaround solution.

```
df1 <- subset(df, a == 1)
table(df1$b)
df2 <- subset(df, a == 2)
table(df2$b)
rm(df1, df2)
```

Is there a simpler way?

Also, I feel like I am spamming with ultra-basic questions like these. If anyone has a suggestion on how I could have found the answer directly I'd be happy to hear it. Other than trying some code myself, I googled terms like 'r apply filter to table', 'r filter table function', 'r table subset dataframe', etc.

Comment: I think the range of answers you received here shows that this question wasn't ultra-basic, but in general googling is the method I'd use.  For some fun, you could try ChatGPT:  don't believe the answer it gives, but it might trigger some ideas.

Comment: True, I thought it'd just require another argument within ```table(df$b)``` that I couldn't find. Didn't expect a multitude of ways to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `table()` on the whole dataframe, and pull out the parts you want afterwards.  You convert the `a` and `b` values to character values when indexing into the two-way table.  For example,

```r
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
b <- c(1,3,99,99,2,3,2,99,1,1)
df <- cbind.data.frame(a,b)

full <- table(df$a, df$b)
full["1",] # corresponds to subset a == 1
#>  1  2  3 99 
#>  1  1  1  2
full["2",] # corresponds to subset a == 2
#>  1  2  3 99 
#>  2  1  1  1

full[, "99"] # corresponds to subset b == 99
#> 1 2 
#> 2 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `99` are your `NA`s then there is a way using `purrr` package, which I find is excellent to see how many NAs there are in each column:

```
library(purrr)
df |> 
  map_df(~sum(. == 99))
```

```
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     0     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide an example of the structure of the original data (multi-national survey)?

Probably you would be able to answer your question with a much tidier code using the package dplyr with functions such as

```
survey_data %>%
  select(column1, column2, country, etc) %>%  #choose your desired columns
  group_by(country) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an example of the structure? For what it's worth the code works and I was indeed looking for a "one-liner" like this. Forgot to specify that the 99s are the NAs, but I resolved that by replacing the 'sum(is.na(.))' by '(b == 99)'. However, applying this solution to my real dataset produces a strange warning, I'll post it in a follow-up. Can I just ignore this?

Comment: Warning message:
`funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 

  # Simple named list: 
  list(mean = mean, median = median)

  # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
  tibble::lst(mean, median)

  # Using lambdas
  list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.

Answer (score 2):

You could `split` on your a variable and use `lapply` to use `table` on each list like this:

```r
lapply(split(df, df$a), \(x) table(x))
#> $`1`
#>    b
#> a   1 2 3 99
#>   1 1 1 1  2
#> 
#> $`2`
#>    b
#> a   1 2 3 99
#>   2 2 1 1  1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Just use it in an `lapply`.

```
alv <- unique(df$a)
lapply(alv, \(x) table(subset(df, a == x, b))) |> setNames(alv)
# $`1`
# b
# 1  2  3 99 
# 1  1  1  2 
# 
# $`2`
# b
# 1  2  3 99 
# 2  1  1  1
```

However, it might be better to code `99` (and probably others) as `NA`,

```
df[] <- lapply(df, \(x) replace(x, x %in% c(99), NA))
```

and count the `NA`s in *b* for each individual *a*.

```
with(df, tapply(b, a, \(x) sum(is.na(x))))
# 1 2 
# 2 1
```